# text style not work in custom text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, textview

this is my custom text class:

```
public class CustomTXT  extends TextView {


    public CustomTXT(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "gandom-bold.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(face);
    }

    public CustomTXT(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "gandom-bold.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(face);
    }

    public CustomTXT(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "gandom-bold.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(face);
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


    }

}
```

but in xml layout when use android:textStyle="bold" for custom text , text style not work!
i try to use set text style programmatically like this :

```
title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            title.setTypeface(title.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

work fine but when become end of recyclerview app crash and give this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.erfan.memaraneha.maghalat.DataAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(DataAdapter.java:94)
```

from this line :

```
 title.setTypeface(title.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

and this is my adapter :

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    List<jsonContent> jcontent;



    public DataAdapter(Context context,List<jsonContent> jcontent) {

        this.context=context;
        this.jcontent=jcontent;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

       View view;
        if(i == R.layout.card_row) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        }else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button_card, viewGroup, false);
        }
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder,int i) {


        if(i == jcontent.size()) {
            viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {

            viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);

            Picasso.with(context).load(jcontent.get(i).imgurl).resize(300, 400).into(viewHolder.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

            return jcontent.size()+1;

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == jcontent.size()) ? R.layout.button_card : R.layout.card_row;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView title;

        private ImageView imageView;

        private Button button;

        public ViewHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);


           title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            title.setTypeface(title.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);

            imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
            button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.loadmore);



            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),card_activity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    String passingdata = title.getText().toString();
                    b.putString("Key", passingdata);
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to set it *Programatically*.

Comment: @jaydroider try that way but my text view in adapter and when i set typeface for my txtview in adapter app give me null exception error

Comment: Post that code in above question with exception log.

Comment: @jaydroider edit my question

Comment: Post your full error log...
And try with debugging..Are you getting title object null?

Comment: i explain completely about my question and my error! and i give up for do this cause seems cant possible :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some try i use this line

```
viewHolder.title.setTypeface(viewHolder.title.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

under

```
viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);
```

in my onBindViewHolder and problem solve

Answer (score 0):

Use this, this is working :

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set *Type Face* below this line. Remove it from *ViewHolder*. Your *font*
 file should be inside *asset/fonts* folder.

```
viewHolder.title.setText(jcontent.get(i).title);

Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/gandom-bold.ttf"); 

viewHolder.title.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: cant recognize getAssets()

Comment: nope not work!  title.setTypeface(title.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD); it only way till now work but dont know why when become end of recyclerview app crash ...

Answer (score 0):

Pass Text style in your Custom Textview when setting TypeFace. I changed your Custom Textview class. This will work hopefully.

```
public class CustomTXT  extends TextView {


public CustomTXT(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "gandom-bold.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
}

public CustomTXT(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "gandom-bold.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
}

public CustomTXT(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "gandom-bold.ttf");
    this.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
}

protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


}
```

I added "Typeface.BOLD" in setTypeFace method so you no longer need to set textStyle explicitly in xml or in your Java code.